# Laravel - SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, laravel, database-migration

Hello im getting this error Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message `'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'posts.user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from`posts`where`posts`.`user_id`= 1 and`posts`.`user_id`is not null)'` and I don't know why if in my database I don't have user_id, I have id_user...

This is my migration table

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('user')->unique();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password', 60);
            $table->string('img');

            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }
}
```

This other is my posts migration archive

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AddPosts extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nombre');
            $table->longText('contenido');

            $table->unsignedInteger('id_user');

            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('posts', function($table) {
          $table->foreign('id_user')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('posts');
    }
}
```

this is my Post model

```
<?php

namespace NacionGrita;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    protected $table = "posts";
    protected $fillable = ['nombre', 'contenido', 'id_user'];

    public function imagenes()  {
      return $this->belongsToMany('NacionGrita\Imagen');
    }
    public function categorias()  {
      return $this->belongsToMany('NacionGrita\Categoria');
    }
    public function tags() {
      return $this->belongsToMany('NacionGrita\Tag');
    }
    public function user()  {
      return $this->belongsTo('NacionGrita\User');
    }

}
```

and this is my users Model

```
<?php

namespace NacionGrita;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;


class User extends Model
{

    protected $table = "users";
    protected $fillable = [
        'user', 'email', 'password', 'img'
    ];

    public function posts() {
      return $this->hasMany('NacionGrita\Post');
    }

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

If I change my "posts" table column from id_user to user_id it works but I don't know why I have to change the column name if its supposed to works because I specified the foreigns keys or Im doing something wrong?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 7):

In order to specify the foreign keys, you need to do so in the model when you define the relationships.

From the docs for a `belongsTo` relationship:

> In the example above, Eloquent will try to match the `user_id` from the `Phone` model to an `id` on the `User` model. Eloquent determines the default foreign key name by examining the name of the relationship method and suffixing the method name with `_id`. However, if the foreign key on the `Phone` model is not `user_id`, you may pass a custom key name as the second argument to the `belongsTo` method

In other words, in your Post model where you define the relationship with the User, you need to add a second argument that specifies the foreign key name:

```
public function user()  {
  return $this->belongsTo('NacionGrita\User', 'id_user');
}
```

From the docs for a `hasOne` and `hasMany` relationship:

> Eloquent assumes the foreign key of the relationship based on the model name. In this case, the `Phone` model is automatically assumed to have a `user_id` foreign key. If you wish to override this convention, you may pass a second argument to the `hasOne` method:

In other words, in your User model where you define the relationship with the Post, you need to once again add a second argument that specifies the foreign key name:

```
public function posts() {
  return $this->hasMany('NacionGrita\Post', 'id_user');
}
```

Link to docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Thank You so much, sir. yeah, this fixed my problem, I never had to set a new argument because I used the default keyname. Thanks.